# Syntax error unexpected token error in Open cart 1.5.5.1

Tags: syntax-error, opencart

When I add items to an order in backend I got an error like this:

[image]

I have tried to upload the original files and that didn't help! I'm using one.com to host it and I have had several error before this one!

Answer (score 0):

i am having the exact same error and cannot create any orders from admin. Not sure what to do.

I dont think this is related to any host. I had this in dreamhost and i moved to a VPS in a different hosting and have it again now.